# Showing this tridiagonal system of linear equations has a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

Starting with a diagonally dominant tridiagonal $n \times n$ matrix A =
\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
        b & a & b & 0 &... & 0 \\
        0 & b & a & b & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & b & a & b\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b & \frac{a}{2}
        \end{bmatrix}

I want to show the linear system Ax=b, where 
b = \begin{bmatrix}
c\\c\\c\\c\\c\\\frac{c}{2}
\end{bmatrix} has a unique solution.
I know how to find the determinant for a symmetric tridiagonal matrix but I don't the steps for when the main diagonal values are not the same. I can't think of a simple way to show the column vectors are linearly independent and since A isn't strictly diagonally dominant, I can't use any of the conclusions.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to clarify a few things in your question. You first claim that the matrix $A$ is diagonally dominant, type it up as a symmetric matrix and want to study $Ax = b$; so far so good. But then you are asking about a non-symmetric, non-diagonally dominant case, and again refer to it as $A$. What does this matrix look like? And how does it relate to the first version of $A$ above? Which system is it that you want to study?

Comment: A is not **strictly** diagonally dominant. Strictly diagonally dominant matrices are invertible. However, thanks for catching that A is symmetric. I meant that the main-diagonal values differ from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T_0 = 1$ and $T_1 = a/2$ and for all other $n$, let $T_n$ denote the determinant of the $n \times n$ matrix $A$. Expanding along the first row, it is easy to see that the determinant satisfies the following recursion relation:
\begin{align}
T_n &= a T_{n-1} - b^2 T_{n-2} \\
T_0 &= 1 \\
T_1 &= a/2.
\end{align}
The solution is $T_n = 2^{-(n+1)} \left[ \left(a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b^2} \right)^n + \left(a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4b^2} \right)^n \right]$. From what I gather from the question and comment, $A$ is diagonally dominant apart from the last row, which implies that $|a| \geq |2b|$. I'll also boldly assume that $a>0$ (else, repeat the analysis for $-A$). It follows that $T_n > 0$ for all $n$, and thus $A$ is invertible. Uniqueness of the solution follows.

Answer (score 1):

How are you arriving to this Matrix? If it is part of some model then $A$ is positive definite.  If a square matrix $A$ is positive definite then $A$ is invertible
and hence $A\xi = b$ has a unique solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to use this answer. I'm using this matrix to find coefficients of polynomial and not sure how to show A is positive definite for any size of A.